# padding bottom appearing unexpectedly

Tags: html, css

There is no padding value when I inspect element but when I close inspector there I see padding bottom value. The problem is with ja-footerwrap id. What is the problem here with padding?

[please visit this link](http://nepotech.com/thelandmark/index.php)

I have done with css

```
#ja-footerwrap{padding: 20px 0 0 20px;}
```

Where padding-bottom value is 0 but showing padding bottom in webpage.

Comment: Why -votes and close votes?

Comment: I am not the downvoter. What is the problem? you haven't explained it? I can see padding value in css.

Comment: @Mr_Green question is clear about padding bottom appearing unexpectedly

Comment: maybe you should post some code

Comment: @C-Link This much padding is coming in `20px 0 0 20px` for `#ja-footerwrap`

Comment: @swapnesh that means there is no padding bottom value but also it is appearing padding bottom why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `height:100%` from `#ja-component`

I think this will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

reduce height and padding bottom from #ja-component